# Orientation: Landscape showing true for desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Wondering why landscape specific styles are showing true when on desktop?

I have styles specified under `@media (min-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)`. These were specifically for iPad landscape. However, these styes are still applied when on desktop?

Comment: Many desktop monitors can also be rotated, so using them in standard landscape orientation should trigger this, no?

Comment: @connexo, it's not related to hardware capability but raw dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's very simple. Because landscape means if the width of the viewport is bigger then the height of the viewport. And most screens are made like this. So yes your media query is applied on the desktop. The opposite of landscape is portrait. It's a portrait when the the height is greater than or equal to the width. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation

**Example:**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  background: yellow;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Box 1</div>
<div>Box 2</div>
<div>Box 3</div>
```